# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$injector/moduler

Tags: node.js, angularjs, excel, angular-datatables

Am getting the above error in console on loading my application. My controller looks as below.Am new to angular so any help would be appreciated
 Am trying to export the datatable into excel here. I think the issue is here angular.module('myApp','datatables', 'datatables.buttons'])
 What is the correct way to include them in the module?

**ViewCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp',['datatables', 'datatables.buttons'])
    .controller('ViewCtrl', function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {
       $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(2)
        .withDOM('pitrfl')
        .withButtons([{
                extend: 'excelHtml5',

            }
        ]);
 vm.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notVisible(),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notSortable()
  ];
});
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire error?  Verify that you can start your angularjs with a blank controller by removing the injected DTOOptionsBuilder, and DTColumnDefBuilder, then commenting out the variable. vm.dtColumnDefs and $scope.dtOptions. Place a console.log within the controller stating ("Yay! I made it"). If you can get the console.log to show, then the injected ['datatables', 'datatables.buttons''] may not be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the console loads. If the console.log does not show and you still get the inject error, then your problem is likely the datatables and datatables.buttons. Verify that these files are added to your index.html file prior to this file.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['datatables', 'datatables.buttons'])
.controller('ViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    console.log("Code of awesomeness");
});
```

If you find that you do see the console.log("Code of awesomeness"); Then your $inject issue is DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder. Verify spelling.

Comment: Am including my code in an existing code which already has DTOOptionsBuilder, and DTColumnDefBuilder used and it works fine. 
When I included my piece without the  ['datatables', 'datatables.buttons'']  in app.module I get the below error in console

Comment: angular.js:15570 TypeError: DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions(...).withPaginationType(...).withDisplayLength(...).withDOM(...).withButtons is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (app.bundle.js:3689)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5158)
    at angular.js:11722
    at Object.<anonymous> (viewDirective.ts:410)
    at angular.js:1390
    at Ba (angular.js:11269)
    at p (angular.js:10588)
    at g (angular.js:9835)
    at angular.js:9700
    at angular.js:10114 "<ui-view class="ng-scope">"

but the above functions are already been used in the code. Am I missing to include any JS?

Comment: I did install the below packages
datatables.net
datatables.net-dt
datatables.net-buttons-dt
datatables.net-buttons in bower components

Comment: So .withButtons is not already used and am including it as part of my code. So am I missing to include any JS files. We get all packages from bower_components in gulp and the copy it to vendor folder.